# How to allow slash(/) on page url

Tags: permalinks

Suppose, a url of my wordpress website page is domain.com/journal-submission. How to change the url like domain.com/journal/submission.

When I rename the permalink, give slash(/) instead of dash(-) it's not changing anything. I just want to change some of my page url keeping the same permalink settings.

Now the permalink is set to post-name [https://theiacs.org/sample-post/].

Comment: have you tried creating a parent page named `journal`?

Comment: Thanks, it works. Can you please add ans,  I will mark as  right ans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the slug to `submission` then create a parent page named `journal`